# websphere application server 8.5.5 create profile failed

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

Getting INSTCONFFAILED: The profile could not be created when using PMT.bat to create new profile in windows server 2012.

The exception in creation log are 
com.ibm.wsspi.profile.WSProfileException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 11: /C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties/profileRegistry.xml

Anyway I can by pass the space in the path ( com.ibm.wsspi.profile.WSProfileException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 11: /C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties/profileRegistry.xml)?

Comment: Using  `Program files` folder is not recommended. I'd suggest something like `c:\IBM\WebSphere`, then you dont need to deal with all the spacing problem.

Comment: re-installation will be last option because the server is in production environment